# Loop control shift in R

Tags: r, loops

I am Having a problem in r i want my loops to flow in the following way

```
for(){
  for(){
    if( a certain condition is met){
      (control shifts to the next iteration of first loop.)
    }
  }
}
```

any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way and it worked.

for(j in 1:dcl){

if (double_check[j]==comp){

dcj<-1

}

}

if(dcj == 1){

next

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [break & next](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html). The former breaks out of a loop, while the latter skips to the next iteration (of the innermost loop).

Comment: I tried it with break but i don't know why it breaks out of both loops still executing commands in outer loop

Comment: Provide a reproducible example of the problem and show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Lyngbakr is obviously right, everything works as documented in the docs, see the help page `?break`.

```
x <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3)

for(i in 1:4){
    for(j in 1:3){
        if(j == 3)
            break
        else
            cat(x[i, j], "\t")
    }
    cat("\n")
}
```